# Phython script to compare and generate ticket

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a Python script to generate ticket from an Active Alert csv file. But before generating a ticket i need to compare it with an incident ticket csv file which keep  all the tickets raised for the Alert ID and if the ticket date is less than 3 days.. raise a new one and update the csv2
Apologies for my limited Python scripting knowledge
CSV1

```
Alert_ID    Country     Severity    Timestamp
1234        US      Critical    2023-03-23 00:12:13     
1235        UK      Critical    2023-03-23 00:11:14 
1236        SG      Critical    2023-03-23 00:11:13 
1237        HK      Critical    2023-03-23 00:16:13    


CSV2
Alert_ID    Incident_No     Timestamp
1234        INC01           2023-02-17  
1235        INC02           2023-02-18
1236        INC03           2023-02-19
1237        INC04           2023-02-19 
1234        INC01           2023-02-20  
1235        INC02           2023-02-23 
1236        INC03           2023-02-23 
1237        INC04           2023-02-23
```

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from datetime import datetime,date
csv2 = pd.read_csv('.c:\temp\csv2.csv')
cav1 = pd.read_csv('c:\temp\csv1.csv')
if csv1[~csv1['Alert_id'].isin csv2['Alert_ID'])]
      Raise ticket
      update csv2
eleif csv1[csv1['Alert_id'].isin csv2['Alert_ID'])] & (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - 
       csv2['timestamp'] ) < 4
       Raise ticket
       update csv2 
else
       ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you want to modify the files. Need details with expected result. To filter, you can do the following.

You have 'Alert_id' and 'Alert_ID' and in tables all: 'Alert_ID'. I added a couple of rows to csv1 so that the condition matches.

```
   Alert_ID Country  Severity           Timestamp
0      1234      US  Critical 2023-03-23 00:12:13
1      1235      UK  Critical 2023-03-23 00:11:14
2      1236      SG  Critical 2023-03-23 00:11:13
3      1237      HK  Critical 2023-03-23 00:16:13
4      1238      HK  Critical 2023-03-23 00:16:13
5      1239      HK  Critical 2023-03-23 00:16:13
```

csv1

```
   Alert_ID Incident_No  Timestamp
0      1234       INC01 2023-02-17
1      1235       INC02 2023-02-18
2      1236       INC03 2023-02-19
3      1237       INC04 2023-02-19
4      1234       INC01 2023-02-20
5      1235       INC02 2023-02-23
6      1236       INC03 2023-02-23
7      1237       INC04 2023-02-23
```

csv2

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

csv1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(csv1['Timestamp'])
csv2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(csv2['Timestamp'])

aaa = csv1[~csv1['Alert_ID'].isin(csv2['Alert_ID'])]

bbb = csv2[((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - csv2['Timestamp']).dt.days) < 40]
fff = csv1[csv1['Alert_ID'].isin(bbb['Alert_ID'])]
```

To filter by days, you need to separately select these rows in bbb and then submit them to isin for comparison. Changed 4 days to 40 days to trigger the condition.